# How to check SQL State in a if statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to commit an insert in a trigger based on a sql state based on success of a previous query in a trigger. But I'm getting a syntax error.
Can anyone point out what's wrong I'm doing here.

```
SET @OLDTMP_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_exp_register` AFTER INSERT ON `trnInvDtl` FOR EACH ROW begin
  insert into trninvdtl_exportregister(comp_code,
       inv_type,
       inv_no,
       item_srl_no) values(
       new.comp_code,
       new.inv_type,
       new.inv_no,
       new.item_srl_no);

        if (sqlstate='0000') then
            rollback;
        end if;
end//
DELIMITER ;
SET SQL_MODE=@OLDTMP_SQL_MODE;
```

Here's the error message for syntax error.

[Window Title]
xxxx PC: Error

[Content]
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sqlstate='0000') then
            rollback;
        end if;
end' at line 11

[OK]

[Footer]
Find some help on this error

Comment: Can you post the syntax error?

Comment: @Philipp Added in the post.